# How to create a realistic environment using pre-rendered assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5

I’m creating a realistic 3D environment to for people to roam around. I want to load the environment in parts in the background and want to show the whole environment using some kind of a way to use the pre-rendered assets if possible so that the realistic quality environment can be shown. There will be only one character which will be able to move in the environment to see and experience. Is there any way so that I can pre-process or render on the backend and serve the assets in the app so that processing power on the app can be saved?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions :grin:

Comment: you can bake lightingm, but if you truly want them to wander and be able to see from different angles, no not easily